# Correct way to write only the first element of a c++ stl vector

Tags: c++, vector

I have a c++ code that at one part it stored some values of a measurement in a vector and this vector is a part of set of data schema which is serialized and then sent to a streamer.
There is new requirement that for a specific case I need just one value of the measurement which is always rewritten with the latest one, but I don't want to change the vector variable in order to keep the same schema. So I thought that for that case to rewrite each time the first element of the vector, something like this

```
vector<int> store_measurements;
int measurement = 10;

if (condition == "several_values") 
   {
      store_measurements.pushback(measurement);
   }
else  
   {
      store_measurements.at(0) = measurement ;
   }
```

It seems to work fine when the vector is not cleared, but I'd like to ask if this is the correct way to do that or there is a more preferable way to do it?

Comment: It really depends.  Do you clear the vector after you serialize it?  Will you always have at least one elements in the vector?  Do you not need to clear out the other measurements before you add the single one?

Comment: You can use `operator []` as well if its always zeroth index. `at` does boundary checking as well

Comment: Aside this `if (condition = "several_values")` is not doing what you expect.

Comment: Please, consider that `std::vector::at()` as well as `std::vector::operator[]()` as well as `std::vector::front()` fails if vector is empty. Too be really sure, you should insert this: `store_measurements.resize(1);` before accessing first value. Btw. this gets rid of additional values which might be still there.

Comment: @NathanOliver I always clear the vector  before I store measurements, and the vector will have always at least one value. The case is either multiple or one value not combined.

Comment: @dk13 If you do, and the vector is empty, then your code should not work.

Comment: can you please show real code? For one the method is called `push_back` and then it is unclear what you mean with "working fine" when you call `at(0)` on an empty vector

Comment: @user463035818 sorry for that but it is a huge project with repeated code and different classes which makes it difficult for me to add code that makes sense . But you are right the case that it worked was for a vector that was not cleared I'll rephrase my question

Comment: please read about [mcve]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `front()` function.

```
vector<int> store_measurements;
int measurement = 10;

if (condition == "several_values") 
{
  store_measurements.push_back(measurement);
}
else  
{
  store_measurements.resize(1);
  store_measurements.front() = measurement ;
}
```

**Edit:**
Based on the comments I added `store_measurements.resize(1);` before the assignment

Comment: You might want to say that if there is no element in the vector then this is undefined behavior.  At least `at` would throw a nice exception where this could do anything.

Comment: This fails if `store_measurements` is empty. Insert `store_measurements.resize(1);` before assignment to make this fool-prove.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use `assign()` which *replaces* all the values in the vector like this:

```
if (condition == "several_values")
{
    store_measurements.push_back(measurement);
}
else
{
    store_measurements.assign(1, measurement);
}
```